# ¿Cómo forzar que todas las peticiones de imágenes de una ip vayan a otra ip manteniendo la ruta?

Tags: .htaccess

Estoy intentando que todos los recursos de mi `www.web_a.com/img/image.png` apunten a mi `www.web_b.com/img/image.png`, es decir cambio únicamente el dominio no la ruta, he investigado y he encontrado los hotlinks pero la negación, como sería el forzado?

Un ejemplo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://i.imgur.com/qX4w7.gif [L]
```

### Actualizo: solucionado

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mi_otra_web.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: No edites la pregunta para poner "solucionado". En su lugar, escribe una respuesta y márcala como aceptada